# How to get all registered types in ContainerBuilder

Tags: c#, autofac

So I have 2 classes named `InputOverNetwork` and `InputFromLocal`, the class `InputOverNetwork` has an attribute `RequiresNetwork` and `InputOverNetwork` is not the only class that has this attribute (other class that requires networking has this attribute), there are other classes that has the `RequiresNetwork` attribute which means that a special class that handles network inputs named `NetListener` should be registered to the Autofac `ContainerBuilder`, now based on the user's input if they want to take inputs from the network or local inputs (these are keystrokes) my program will build and register the required classes for the application, to the `ContainerBuilder`, but to do so I need to check all the classes registered inside the `ContainerBuilder` if one class has the attribute `RequiresNetwork` then I will have to register the class `NetListener` which handles the networking and inputs from another computer on the same LAN.

But the problem is I have no way to check which classes are registered on the `ContainerBuilder` because it's based on the user's input which my program decides which classes to register, is there a way I can get like an `IEnumerable` of the registered types or instances inside the `ContainerBuilder`?

If I do I can just easily decide if there is at least once class that has the `RequiresNetwork` attribute then I register the `NetListener` class.

Comment: Why not just always register your `NetListener` (either via `.RegisterType<NetListener>()` or `.Register(c => new NetListener(…))`), and then if it needs to be instantiated to satisfy a dependency it will be, and if nothing requires, then it won’t be instantiated at all?

Comment: You can register millions of dependencies in container, why you should register it based on user input? User input is a runtime dependency, not compilation time dependency. Just map your user input to required dependency (by name, interface, other data) and retrieve it from container.

Comment: @Iridium yeahh but wont that kinda waste resources? i mean im not initializalizing `NetListener` anywhere

Comment: The resource usage of an unused registration seems likely to be pretty trivial.